# Let $f(x)=\frac{2x+1}{\sin(x)}$ find $f'(x)$

Tags: derivatives

> Let $$f(x)=\frac{2x+1}{\sin(x)}$$ Find $f'(x).$

I used Quotient Rule 
$$\begin {align*}\frac{\sin(x)2-(2x+1)\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\\
=\frac{3-2x\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} \end {align*}$$

Is that right? I don't know how to get the answer.
Please help me out, thanks.

Comment: Please check what I edit in your question.

Comment: It is true if $x≠kπ$.

Comment: Not even. Take for example $\,x=\pi/4\,$

Comment: @DonAntonio: I took $k\in\mathbb Z$. But I am sorry I did not see he omit one sin($x)$ of denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have some serious problems with the algebra involved. Part of the problem is failure to use necessary parentheses: the result of applying the quotient rule is

$$\frac{2\sin x-(2x+1)\cos x}{\sin^2x}\;,$$

where the parentheses around $2x+1$ are absolutely necessary. If you choose to multiply out the numerator, you should get

$$\frac{2\sin x-2x\cos x-\cos x}{\sin^2x}\;.$$

Alternatively, you can split it into two fractions:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{2\sin x-(2x+1)\cos x}{\sin^2x}&=\frac{2\sin x}{\sin^2x}-\frac{(2x+1)\cos x}{\sin^2x}\\\\
&=2\csc x-(2x+1)\cot x\csc x\\\\
&=\csc x\Big(2-(2x+1)\cot x\Big)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 4):

You had (or should) $$\frac{2\sin x-2x\cos x-\cos x}{\sin^2x}$$ and this can't possibly equal what you wrote (where does that $\,3\,$ come from?)

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x)=\frac{2x+1}{\sin(x)}$$

As for the derivative of such a fractional function:

$$f'(x)=\frac{(2x+1)'(\sin x)-(\sin x)'(2x+1)}{\sin^2 x}$$

Simplifying:

$$f'(x)=\frac{2(\sin x)-\cos x(2x+1)}{\sin^2 x}=\frac{2\sin x-2x\cos x-\cos x}{\sin^2 x}=2\csc x-(2x+1) \cot x \csc x$$